# How do I correctly concat JSON using Ionic Angular?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, concatenation

I can't seem to correctly concat "myURL". I tried playing around to get it, but all I'm getting is undefined. Here is the JSON:

```
  "cars": [
    {
      "code": "0000",
      "phone": "",
      "countryCode": "",
      "languages": {
        "en": {
          "title": "Super Car",
          "myUrl": "http://www.qwerty.com",
          }
       }
    },
    {
      "code": "0001",
      "phone": "",
      "countryCode": "",
      "languages": {
        "en": {
          "title": "Mega Car",
          "myUrl": "http://www.asdfg.com",
          }
       }
    }
```

This is the code:

```
const carInfo = eval('defaultData.content.cars.languages' + this.myVarService.defaultLanguage + '.myUrl');
```

How do I get myURL?

Comment: What are you trying to obtain exactly? Can you include a sample of the expected output?

Comment: The `dot` after `languages` is missing. `'defaultData.content.cars.languages.' + this.myVarService.defaultLanguage + '.myUrl'`

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu
The output should be: ```http://www.asdfg.com```

Comment: Please post your complete code of what you have tried so far. Code fragments are not enough to answer this question.